# Scheduling events in laravel

Tags: php, time, laravel-4

I want to setup a system for a privileged user to create a new task to run from date/time X to date/time Y saved in MySQL or SQLite? The task will send out a request to remote server via SSH and when the end date/time is up another SSH request would be sent.

What I'm not sure about is how to actually trigger the event at the start time and howto trigger the other at the end time?

Should I be polling the server somehow every 1min (sounds like a performance hit) or setup jobs in Iron.io/Amazon SQS or something else?

I noticed Amazon SQS only allows messages to queue for up to 14 days, how would that work for events weeks or months in the future?

Im not looking for code, just the idea on how it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are two solutions, but maybe a hybrid version suits your problem best...

1. Use a queue (build into Laravel) and set up delayed jobs in the queue to be fired later on. You already mention that this might not be the best solution when a task takes months/weeks.
2. Use a cron job. Downside with this is that you can check once every day but that could mean a delay of 23h59m or you can check every minute but that might give you performance issues (in most cases it kind of works, but definitely not perfect).

Combining 1 & 2 might be the best solution; check in de beginning of a day whether there are tasks going to end in the coming day. If so, schedule a job in the queue to end the task at the exact time at which it should end. This gives you scalability and the possibility to create tasks that end a year after they where created.